# Regular Expressions for identifying harvard citations

Tags: c#, regex

This is the regular expression I used to identify Harvard-style citations in a windows forms application using C#.

```
\([a-zA-Z]*\,\s[0-9_]*\
```

Citation example :

```
(Barnes, 1997)
```

but citing two or more authors, the regular expression doesn't locate them.

Citation example :

```
(Smith, 2001; Brown & Black, 2007)
```

Please tell me a way to overcome the problem.

Comment: Are there any rules, specifications of what constitutes a harvard citation and what doesn't? What is the output you're looking for exactly? `Smith, 2001; Brown & Black, 2007` or two separate ones `Smith, 2001` then `Brown & Black, 2007`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  \(([\w\&\.\s]+,\s\d{4}(;\s+[\w\&\.\s]+,\s\d{4})*)\)
```

Should be more like that. Add other symbols that can be present in the author name

You can also add more capture groups if you need too.